# Batch saving multiple rendered images in QGIS

Tags: raster, pyqgis, export, batch, categorized-renderer

Using 3.16.3-Hannover

I have multiple images with a an applied singleband pseudocolor symbology. I'm looking for a way to batch export them. I came across the following code, but it exports the raw data from selected layers, and not the rendered image.

```
layers = iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers()
for layer in layers:
    file_name = 'path' + layer.name() + '.tif'
    file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter(file_name)
    pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
    provider = layer.dataProvider()

    if not pipe.set(provider.clone()):
        print ("Cannot set pipe provider")
        continue
    
    file_writer.Mode(1)
    file_writer.writeRaster(
        pipe,
        provider.xSize(),
        provider.ySize(),
        provider.extent(),
        provider.crs())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will export all rasters added to the map as rendered. I want JPEG compression so I added COMPRESS=JPEG

```
import os

outfolder = r'C:\GIS\data\DEM50m'

for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    extent = layer.extent()
    width, height = layer.width(), layer.height()
    renderer = layer.renderer()
    provider=layer.dataProvider()
    crs = layer.crs().toWkt()
    pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
    pipe.set(provider.clone())
    pipe.set(renderer.clone())
    out_file = os.path.join(outfolder, f"{layer.name()}_rendered.tif")
    file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter(out_file)
    opts = ["COMPRESS=JPEG"]
    file_writer.setCreateOptions(opts)
    file_writer.writeRaster(pipe, width, height, extent, layer.crs())

print('Done')
```

Comment: Awesome. I changed the JPEG to LZW. Images are looking good. Thanks!